# Sorting in Tablix Computed Column

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc

Friends,

I am using Tablix Control in RDLC to generate matrix report. In the last column of my matrix (group) report I have defined a formula using expression Now my user want to sort this column  by ascending or descending.
(Criteria will be sent to report via Report Parameter).

I found sorting under  Row Group - > Group Properties -> Sorting.....
But I am not sure how to do sorting on column which is calculated based on formula.

How can I do that? Can any one tell?

Answer (score 0):

New answer:

If you do not *need* to use a parameter for triggering this sorting, then Interactive Sorting would accomplish exactly what you are looking for. Right click on the header of the column in question and you should see Interactive Sorting.

If it *needs* to be a parameter for whatever reason, then it would depend on the data type. If it is some kind of numeric type, then you could have the parameter value be either 1 (ascending) or -1 (descending). You would then sort on the parameter multiplied by the expression for that column.

Comment: I already know that ... my question was what shell I add in the FX(expression Button) I am passing parameter with value "DESC" or "ASC"  Based on this parameter the expression should sort.....

Comment: Oh I see that now, sorry about that, missed that the first time. Does it NEED to be set by a parameter? Interactive Sorting would get this done if it does not need to be a parameter. If it does need to be a parameter, then I guess it depends on what the data type is for that column: if it is numerical, then you could have the sorting parameter value either 1 (asc) or -1 (desc), then have your sort by expression be the column value multiplied by the parameter.